# Count events by group per day including 0 in R

Tags: r, count, multiple-columns, days

I want columns counting for events per day including dates without events. This is an example of my data although my real dataset has more than 100 `ID`'s

```
dt <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                            2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), date = c("1/01/2000", "2/01/2000", "2/01/2000",
                                                                          "5/01/2000", "5/01/2000", "5/01/2000", "6/01/2000", "2/01/2000", "3/01/2000", 
                                                                          "3/01/2000", "4/01/2000", "4/01/2000", "4/01/2000", "4/01/2000", 
                                                                          "5/01/2000", "9/01/2000")), .Names = c("id", "date"), 
                row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = "data.frame")
```

What I want is:

```
date       count 1  count 2
1/01/2000    0          0
2/01/2000    2          1
3/01/2000    0          2
4/01/2000    0          4
5/01/2000    3          1
6/01/2000    1          0
7/01/2000    0          0
8/01/2000    0          0
9/01/2000    0          1
```

My real data will be dates from `1/01/2000` to `31/12/2000`. I want all `ID`'s to have all these dates, even if there were zero events during certain days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)[,`:=`(date=as.Date(date, "%Y-%m-%d"),id=paste0("count",id))]
dcast(
  dt[SJ(date=seq(min(date), max(date),1)), on=.(date)],
  date~id,fun.aggregate = length,
)[,`NA`:=NULL]
```

Output:

```
         date count1 count2
1: 2020-01-01      1      0
2: 2020-01-02      2      1
3: 2020-01-03      0      2
4: 2020-01-04      0      4
5: 2020-01-05      3      1
6: 2020-01-06      1      0
7: 2020-01-07      0      0
8: 2020-01-08      0      0
9: 2020-01-09      0      1
```

If you know your dates, as you indicate in the post, you can use those directly:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)[,`:=`(date=as.Date(date, "%Y-%m-%d"), id=paste0("count",id))]
result = dcast(
  dt[SJ(date=seq(as.Date("2020-01-01"), as.Date("2020-12-31"),1)), on=.(date)],
  date~id,fun.aggregate = length,
)[,`NA`:=NULL]
```

Output:

```
           date count1 count2
  1: 2020-01-01      1      0
  2: 2020-01-02      2      1
  3: 2020-01-03      0      2
  4: 2020-01-04      0      4
  5: 2020-01-05      3      1
 ---                         
362: 2020-12-27      0      0
363: 2020-12-28      0      0
364: 2020-12-29      0      0
365: 2020-12-30      0      0
366: 2020-12-31      0      0
```

Input:

```
dt = structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                      2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), date = c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-02", 
                                                        "2020-01-05", "2020-01-05", "2020-01-05", "2020-01-06", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-03", 
                                                        "2020-01-03", "2020-01-04", "2020-01-04", "2020-01-04", "2020-01-04", "2020-01-05", 
                                                        "2020-01-09")), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: In my real dataset I have `date` as `Y-m-d` and character. So instead of using `date=as.Date(date, "%d/%m/%y")` I'm using `date=as.Date(date)`. I can't run the second part of the code because I get `Error: 'to' must be a finite number`

Comment: You can change to `date=as.Date(date,"%Y-%m-%d)`

Comment: If you know your dates, you can insert them directly, rather than using min/max - see edit to solution

Comment: I've updated my input/sample data so it should match your real data (Y-m-d)

Comment: Thanks! Just one more question, if I have `date` already as `class(date)` or `POSIXct` I only need to do the first part of the code as `date=date` right?

Comment: If date is already date class, then you don't have to convert it to date.. the line beginning with `setDT(dt)...`, could be reduced to `setDT(dt)[, id:=paste0("count",id)]`

Answer (score 0):

We may use `complete` and then reshape to 'wide' with `pivot_wider`.  The OP showed the example data with format for 'date' as `month/day/year`.  If the original data is in format `year-month-day` then change the `mdy(date)` to `ymd(date)`

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
dt %>% 
   mutate(date = mdy(date), count = 1) %>% 
   group_by(id = str_c('count', id)) %>%
   complete(date = seq(min(.$date, na.rm = TRUE), 
                      max(.$date, na.rm = TRUE), by = 'month'),
    fill = list(count = 0)) %>% 
   ungroup %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = id, values_from =count, 
        values_fn = sum, values_fill = 0)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 9 × 3
  date       count1 count2
  <date>      <dbl>  <dbl>
1 2000-01-01      1      0
2 2000-02-01      2      1
3 2000-03-01      0      2
4 2000-04-01      0      4
5 2000-05-01      3      1
6 2000-06-01      1      0
7 2000-07-01      0      0
8 2000-08-01      0      0
9 2000-09-01      0      1
```

Comment: In my dataset I have `date` as `character` and as `2000-12-31` so when I try running the code I get `Error in seq.default(min(.$date), max(.$date), by = "month") : 
  'from' must be a finite number`

Comment: @Lilia If you check my code, it is doing `mdy(date)` to convert to `Date` class

Comment: @Lilia i assume there are no NA elements.  If there are, then use the updated i.e. `na.rm = TRUE` in `min/max`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R option using `table` + `seq` + `factor`

```
with(
    transform(
        dt,
        date = as.Date(date, "%d/%m/%Y")
    ),
    table(
        factor(date,
            levels = as.character(seq(min(date), max(date), 1))
        ),
        id
    )
)
```

which gives

```
            id
             1 2
  2000-01-01 1 0
  2000-01-02 2 1
  2000-01-03 0 2
  2000-01-04 0 4
  2000-01-05 3 1
  2000-01-06 1 0
  2000-01-07 0 0
  2000-01-08 0 0
  2000-01-09 0 1
```

---

Or, we can step further with `reshape` + `as.data.frame` if we want data.frame output

```
reshape(
    as.data.frame(
        with(
            transform(
                dt,
                date = as.Date(date, "%d/%m/%Y")
            ),
            table(
                factor(date,
                    levels = as.character(seq(min(date), max(date), 1))
                ),
                id
            )
        )
    ),
    idvar = "Var1",
    timevar = "id",
    direction = "wide"
)
```

which gives

```
        Var1 Freq.1 Freq.2
1 2000-01-01      1      0
2 2000-01-02      2      1
3 2000-01-03      0      2
4 2000-01-04      0      4
5 2000-01-05      3      1
6 2000-01-06      1      0
7 2000-01-07      0      0
8 2000-01-08      0      0
9 2000-01-09      0      1
```